# Upgrade Angular 2 to Angular 4 has no exported member 'AnimationDriver'

Tags: angular

I have upgraded Angular 2 to Angular 4. When I run my project I am facing the below error.

> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'AnimationDriver'.

Comment: It is a known and open issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15332). The Angular Team is working on it as of today.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc1-2017-02-24

> Animation Package
>
> We have pulled Animations into their own package. This means that if
>   you don’t use Animations, this extra code will not end up in your
>   production bundles. This also allows you to more easily find
>   documentation and to take better advantage of autocompletion. If you
>   do need animations, libraries like Material will automatically import
>   the module (once you install it via NPM), or you can add it yourself
>   to your main NgModule.

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest --save
```

```
@angular/animations/browser
```

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

See also the Plunker in

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15190#issuecomment-287972812
- http://angularjs.blogspot.co.at/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Comment: import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ]
}) STILL IT SHOWING AN ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!!! PLEASE GUIDE TO FIX THIS ISSUE

Comment: And this did or did not solve the problem? Check the linked Plunker. You might also need to update your config.

Comment: Hi suppose if i dont want animation "how to remove? can u please guide how to remove it?"

Comment: Remove from where?

Comment: angular 4 upgradation it includes animation i have inlcuded in system.config code in my _layout.html and also app.module.ts it shows an error  '@angular/animations' sysntax error in system.config in _layout.html.So i dont want animation in my project.Which means  if you don’t use Animations what i have to do? code below :System.config({            map: {       '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations@4.0.0-rc.5/bundles/animations.umd.js',
                '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations@4.0.0-rc.5/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js' },packages: { ...

Comment: when i remove it config and app.module again it is showing "@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'AnimationDriver'." Please guide this.

Comment: That's probably because it's somewhere used in your code or 3rd-party code used in your code. I don't know how to guide you.

Comment: Only one doubt : before upgrade angular 4 i can see AnimationDriver file i in "node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom" path.after upgrade angular 4 these files are gone.is that any relate to the error?

Comment: That was the old place for animation and these files were moved to their own sub-module

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading guide here:

https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/UPGRADE-GUIDE.md

angular-universal github page:

https://github.com/angular/universal

Comment: don't miss this one - helpful info about changes like `UniversalModule` > `BrowserModule`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all dependency and npm install (run in console. in the project folder) them because it was reference some other dependencies. that should hopefully work for you.

```html
npm isntall
```

Answer (score -1):

i resolved this problem by running the following command:

```
npm install
```